# Pageload event in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pageload

I have webform code as below.I need to have this in mvc.. What to use to initialize objext in pageload event in asp.net mvc

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctrl = (Control)Session["ctrl"];
        PrintHelper.PrintWebControl(ctrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC doesn't work on events like ASP classic; there's no "pageload event". Your controller methods correspond to requests sent to the server. You'll need to build the equivalent control in HTML, and then use a form to HTTP POST the data to the server, where it is handled by a controller method.

Answer (score 1):

MVC doesn't have a page load event. Everything is done within actions (the designated method of the controller class that's responsible for handling the request).

Alternatively you can execute code within the view (which is similar to page load). But MVC itself doesn't write up like an ASP site.

Best way to simulate what you're doing is pass the view the model that defines the print control,  then create a display template that you can render within the view (instead of calling print).

Answer (score 0):

All the initialization code should be put in controller's constructor or in an action filter. Btw, asp.net mvc doesn't have controls either

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to events or a page life cycle in ASP.NET MVC is Filtering.  Have a look at this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx